# Move character in to a new line in bash

Tags: bash, character

I have a variable 'p' which has values 'first second third'

```
echo $p
first second third
```

I want to make this output as below

```
echo $p
first
second
third
```

Comment: @Aaron That is definitely the wrong duplicate, but this is a common FAQ as such. Maybe see also [the `bash` tag info page](/tags/bash/info) for links to many common beginner questions.

Comment: This was more about substitutions than storing newline characters in variables. And the use of `printf` instead of `echo` is not the solution. I don't think closing questions for wrong reasons is a good thing.

Comment: @Sajana: Try: `echo "${p// /$'\n'}"`. Explanation: `"${p// /$'\n'}"` substitutes all spaces in `p` with a newline character (`$'\n'`).

Comment: `printf "%s\n" $p`